# Problem with #1's in DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I've entered the following functions into my notebook, but the solution to them contains #1's that I can't seem to make any sense of. The functions are:

```
z := R[r, t]
P := D[R[r, t], t]
eqn := P^2 - (2 x[r])/z - 2 y[r] == 0 
sol = DSolve[eqn, z, t]
```

and the solution returns the following:

```
{
 {R[r, t] -> 
  InverseFunction[-((Log[Sqrt[#1] y[r] + Sqrt[y[r]] Sqrt[x[r] + #1 y[r]]] x[r])/
    y[r]^(3/2)) + (Sqrt[#1] Sqrt[x[r] + #1 y[r]])/y[r] &][-Sqrt[2]t + C[1]]}, 
 {R[r, t] -> 
  InverseFunction[-((Log[Sqrt[#1] y[r] + Sqrt[y[r]] Sqrt[x[r] + #1 y[r]]] x[r])/
    y[r]^(3/2)) + (Sqrt[#1] Sqrt[x[r] + #1 y[r]])/y[r] &][Sqrt[2] t + C[1]]}
}
```

Any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: I hate to ask this, but have you looked up [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseFunction.html) in the documentation? What about [`#`](http://reference.wolfram.com/documentation-search.html?query=%23&collection=reference&lang=en)?

Comment: Yes, I've looked up both. The # function appears to be a placeholder, whereas the InverseFunction simply implies that you the function inside the square brackets after InverseFunction should be inversed i.e. InverseFunction[f^-1(x)]=f(x)

Comment: Yes, it is a placeholder, and if you dig a bit deeper you'll see it is a parameter in a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html). Then we are left with the construct: `InverseFunction[pureFunction][Sqrt[2] t + C[1]]`. Any thoughts on what it is doing? Hint: what does `InverseFunction[pureFunction]` return?

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean here. I'm just trying to lead you along in your thinking. The key is in how to think of constructs like `f[a][b]`. It is possible to define such things directly, but more simply they should be thought of as `(f[a])[b]`. So, `f[a]` returns something which `b` is then passed to. If `f = 5`, you'd get `5[b]` which is nonsensical, but if you could return a function ...

Answer (score 7):

#### InverseFunction

`InverseFunction[f]` yields a function that, given an argument y, gives a result x for which `y==f[x]` holds. That is to say:

```
f[x_] = x + x^2;
g = InverseFunction[f];

g[6]
```

> -3

```
f[-3]
```

> 6

Take care here because, as always with inverse functions, it's not necessarily the case that $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$. Here, f maps both 2 and -3 to 6, but the inverse can take you back to only one value. *Mathematica* chose to map back to 3 in this case (and throws a warning message).

#### Pure functions

A pure function is specified in Mathematica using a `Slot` (#) and `&` syntax.

```
#^2+1&
```

In this example is a function with one argument. It squares its argument and adds 1. It can be used directly on an argument like so:

```
#^2 + 1 &[2]
```

> 5

or by first assigning it to a function name and then applying it to an argument:

```
h = #^2 + 1 &;
h[2]
```

> 5

Instead of plain `Slot` you can also use multiple arguments that are numbered like `#1`, `#2`, `#3` etc.

```
m = #1/Cosh[#2] &;
m[5, 3]
```

> 5 Sech[3]

Pure functions can have inverses defined in the same way as above.

```
InverseFunction[#^2 &][2]
```

> During evaluation of In[46]:= InverseFunction::ifun: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses. >>
>
> -Sqrt[2]

#### The rather complex `InverseFunction` in the question

If we study the `InverseFunction` in the question:

```
InverseFunction[-((Log[Sqrt[#1] y[r] + Sqrt[y[r]] Sqrt[x[r] + #1 y[r]]] x[r])/
y[r]^(3/2)) + (Sqrt[#1] Sqrt[x[r] + #1 y[r]])/y[r] &][-Sqrt[2]t + C[1]]
```

You can see that it can be written as follows:

```
p = -((Log[Sqrt[#1] y[r] + Sqrt[y[r]] Sqrt[x[r] + #1 y[r]]] x[r])/
y[r]^(3/2)) + (Sqrt[#1] Sqrt[x[r] + #1 y[r]])/y[r] &;
q = -Sqrt[2]t + C[1]
```

`p` is admittedly a baroque beast, but it's just a pure function like the simple `#^2 + 1 &` above. It is a function of one argument (I only see #1's).

And with

```
r=InverseFunction[p]
```

the rule outputs of your `DSolve` are just

```
r[q],
```

The inverse function acting on the argument q, where `C[1]` is an unspecified constant that is part of the solution because no initial or boundary condition was given.